# Code reverts back to original theme after a while

Tags: css, wordpress, sftp, styling

Apologies for such an amateur question, I can't find the answer anywhere else after searching.

I have a pre-installed theme on WordPress for which I have used an SFTP to make minor code changes to my site. Just little things like changing the hardcoded footer text, the CSS and a slight tweak to a php file, that all worked perfectly. However, this is the 3rd time I have had to make these same changes because I will log in one day and all my changes have disappeared without me doing anything. It just reverts back to the original theme.

Why could this be?

I don't have a child theme which I know I should sort out, but could not having a child theme be the reason it reverts back?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely modifying a theme that gets updated automatically. Your changes get overwritten by the updated official version. If you want to keep your changes, you'll have to use a child theme or make a plugin, depending on what kind of changes you want to make.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Any changes made to a theme or plugin that gets updated via WordPress (manually or automatically) will be overwritten during the update process. The ways around this are to use a [Child Theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/), a separate plugin, or even an [MU-Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) (where the plugin file effectively acts like a separate `functions.php` file)

Comment: Thank you - I will set up a child theme